# Alignat wrong spacing

Tags: align, alignat

I want the `\Leftrightarrow` to be directely above the `\kappa` from the last line. If this is not possible i would be ok if one can put the `\Leftrightarrow` directely above the equals sign (from the last line).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
\hat \pi_t & = \kappa \Tilde{y_t} + \beta E_t[\hat \pi_{t+1}] \quad &\Leftrightarrow \qquad \qquad \gamma_\pi a_t &= \kappa \gamma_y a_t + \beta \gamma_\pi a_{t+1} \\
\gamma_\pi a_t &= \kappa \gamma_y a_t + \beta \gamma_\pi \rho_a a_t   \quad &\Leftrightarrow \quad \gamma_\pi - \beta \gamma_\pi \rho_a &= \kappa \gamma_y \\
&&\gamma_\pi = \frac{\kappa}{(1-\beta \rho_a)} \gamma_y
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what "align the last lines kappa (or equals-) sign with the equivalents signs above" means. Right now, the red lines drawn between rows 2 and 3 make it look like the `\Leftrightarrow` symbol in row 2 is supposed to be aligned *simultaneously* with `=` and `\kappa` in row 3, which cannot be what you're intending.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your help, i tried to specify my question.

Comment: I'm not sure that *any* of the symbols should be aligned, except for the two `\Leftrightarrow` symbols. The look is very unbalanced and awkward to read. In my opinion, an encompassing `gather*` with `alignedat` for the first two rows, using left alignment for the equations and centering the third row, with some vertical space added would be better. [Here's a  picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igtDo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `eqparbox` , to have the `=` of the last equation centred w.r.t. `\Leftrightarrow`  and `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand*{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
\hat \pi_t & = \kappa \Tilde{y_t} + \beta E_t[\hat \pi_{t+1}] & &\Leftrightarrow &\gamma_\pi a_t &= \kappa \gamma_y a_t + \beta \gamma_\pi a_{t+1} \\
\gamma_\pi a_t &= \kappa \gamma_y a_t + \beta \gamma_\pi \rho_a a_t & &\eqmathbox{{}\Leftrightarrow{}} &\gamma_\pi - \beta \gamma_\pi \rho_a &= \kappa \gamma_y \\
&& \mathllap{\gamma_\pi} &\eqmathbox{=} \mathrlap{\frac{\kappa}{(1-\beta \rho_a)} \gamma_y}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is going into the right direction. However i want the `\gamma a_t` in the first line to be right aligned (near to the equal sign on the right) without space.

Comment: @Armenthus: Please see my edited answer. It was enough to move the last but one & in the first two rows. B.t.w., you should know that 3 alignment columns require 5 &, not 3.

Comment: Thx i somehow messed up lines and rows :)